# How can I query Edge metadata in Orientdb?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orientdb2.2

I want to know information about an edge named 'own' from metadata, Instead of querying my large graph in which bulk of nodes are present. I want information like all the 'from' and 'to' classes for the edge 'own'.

I have tried this - 
select expand(properties) from (
   select expand(classes) from metadata:schema
) where name = 'Customers'

where i can know information about nodes with class = Customers. Similarly i want to know information about my edge named 'own'. Thanks.

Answer - After suggestion from Allesandro , I am able to do the above thing using . 
create property own.in LINK order

create property own.out LINK customer

select expand(properties) from ( select expand(classes) from metadata:schema ) where name = 'own'

2. Lets consider that this edge named 'own' is created between 10 classes in a way shown here - 
   customer -> own -> order -> own -> order_detail -> own -> item -> own -> ..... so on

Now I want to query metadata for edge own by 
select expand(properties) from (
   select expand(classes) from metadata:schema
) where name = 'Own'

and know that edge is relating all classes in the given sequence.
customer -> order -> order_detail -> item -> ... so on

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly, but you could use

```
select out.@class, in.@class from own
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

If you use some constrains on your class "own" like:

```
create property own.out LINK customer
create property own.in LINK customer
```

you could use

```
select expand(properties) from ( select expand(classes) from metadata:schema ) where name = 'own'
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks For this. But in this case am actually querying my graph. Instead i want to query only metadata for my graph so i dont need to scan through all the records.

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice way. Let me explore it more and I will get back to you. Thanks a lot.